# Office Script - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeaderRowRange')

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, excel-addins, office-scripts

Trying to use the sample code below on my dataset, but keep getting error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeaderRowRange')"

Combine data from multiple Excel tables into a single table
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/copy-tables-combine

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Delete the "Combined" worksheet, if it's present.
  workbook.getWorksheet('Combined')?.delete();

  // Create a new worksheet named "Combined" for the combined table.
  const newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Combined');
  
  // Get the header values for the first table in the workbook.
  // This also saves the table list before we add the new, combined table.
  const tables = workbook.getTables();    
  const headerValues = tables[0].getHeaderRowRange().getTexts();
  console.log(headerValues);

  // Copy the headers on a new worksheet to an equal-sized range.
  const targetRange = newSheet.getRange('A1').getResizedRange(headerValues.length-1, headerValues[0].length-1);
  targetRange.setValues(headerValues);

  // Add the data from each table in the workbook to the new table.
  const combinedTable = newSheet.addTable(targetRange.getAddress(), true);
  for (let table of tables) {      
    let dataValues = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getTexts();
    let rowCount = table.getRowCount();

    // If the table is not empty, add its rows to the combined table.
    if (rowCount > 0) {
      combinedTable.addRows(-1, dataValues);
    }
  }
}
```

Tried cleaning up my dataset so it looks like something below. No luck
[image]

Tried creating a "headed row" manually by copying it from the first sheet, no idea on how to continue

```js
const combined = workbook.getWorksheet("Combined");    combined.getRange("1:1").copyFrom(workbook.getFirstWorksheet().getRange("1:1"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
```

Also tried recording actions to a script but it won't work when there are a large number of sheets.

Comment: comparing my dataset with the example dataset, cannot tell any difference

Comment: all right i see, my dataset is worksheet and i have convert it to table first